# Do I need do the "bcedit" thing in windows safemode if I plan to wipe windows completely and install Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, ahci

I have installed Ubuntu many times but always in dual boot before only. I am planning buying a second laptop to wipe windows to do full new install Ubuntu (with AHCI mode in Bios).

My question is do I still need to do the
**bcdedit /set safeboot minimal** thing in safe mode in windows, before I set Bios to AHCI mode, (and boot windows safe mode again and repeat etc) prior to doing a fresh/full install of Ubuntu? I remember I had do that before to keep wondows dual-boot? But I am now planning just doing a full wipe windows and full Ubuntu install.

So can I just set AHCI mode in bios, then boot into Ubuntu live USB, and then use the installer to just wipe Windows drive completely and do complete Ubuntu install (without doing the whole safeboot bcedit thing in windows) ?

Comment: Yes, just set to AHCI and install Ubuntu,

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I haven't done no  dual-boot in a long time :)   So basically the bcedit code in safeboot in windows pre-install Ubuntu is only if people 'want' keep  their original Windows partition/data am I right?

Comment: People keep their partitions/data anyway as long as they don't touch them. The code you mention is to install AHCI support **in Windows** so it can boot with that drive mode. Not doing that only causes Windows to not boot unless the mode is changed back to the one in which it was preinstalled.